# Android resource linking failed for app icon - error: failed processing manifest

Tags: android, gradle

I am taking an image as a icon with `image asset` submenu on android studio.
When I try to build a singed apk it shows that error. Previously same issue showed and when I deleted mipmap folder and added image asset / icon again then it worked. But currently it is not working on multiple projects.

Error:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\softw\AndroidStudioProjects\QuickDial\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.365.quickdial:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
    C:\Users\softw\AndroidStudioProjects\QuickDial\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:13: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.365.quickdial:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
    error: failed processing manifest.
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.QuickDial"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All the icons and xml files linked on manifest are present in the android studio and can be edited as well.
I would like to know a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete all icons from mipmap, `clean Build` and again create app_icon. I solved this error by doing this.

Comment: Did all of these. I also mentioned deleting mipmap and adding icons again solved such issue previously with older version but not working now. Also invalidated cache and what not.

Comment: Add these launcher icons to drawable, and give path of drawable in manifest `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: Thanks, that made it successfully build. Any suggestion about round icon?

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

1. Delete the `mipmap` folder
2. Add new image asset again by right clicking `res` folder and selecting `New Image Asset`
3. App image should be pre loaded, if not make a new one
4. Click "Next"
5. On the "Confirm Icon Path" screen, select the `main` source set in the top left drop down
6. Click finish and it should now work